# Buildah: what workflow to create image

Tags: docker, containers, devops, buildah

I am used to docker, and to create containers from a Dockerfile, and building / running it again to test and make it work.

I am testing Buildah. I like the way I can create the container on the fly. However I need to saved the way the container was created at a point. Currently I:

- write commands to send commands, copy files ...
- then copy-paste these commands into a bash file
- I will probably git save this bash file.

I don't like this process, how do you personally save your changes in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

buildah bud supports Dockerfile formatted images in addition to the buildah scriptable commands.  Perhaps, given that you are familiar with Docker, would prefer to use the Dockerfile to create your workflow?

```
buildah bud -t tag .
```